# Checking for a substring in unicode value

Tags: python, unicode, substring

Suppose I have a variable that has a unicode value in a Python script.

```
 place_name = u'K\u016bla Mountain'
```

In this instance, `016b` denotes that a macron accent mark is used over the `u`. I want to check for '016b' in the substring and if found, change place_name to `u'Kula Mountain'`. If it was just a string, I could use:

```
if '016b' in place_name:
    place_name = 'Kula Mountain'
```

But that won't work with the unicode value. Whats the simplest way to check for '016b' and if found, change place_name to uncode value of `u'Kula Mountain'`?

Note, I tried:

```
 if '016b' in ord(alt_map_name):
      place_name = u'Kula Mountain'
```

as suggested by other posts on this issue, but got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 16 found
```

EDIT: To be clear, I just want to check for the `macron` (0x016b), be it with a 'u' or any other letter.

Comment: Did you try `u'\u016b' in place_name`?

Comment: `place_name.replace(u"\u016b", "u")` should work, too. (you do not want to replace _all_ place names that have that letter with "Kula Mountain", right?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Comment: @tobais_k - Well, my example is simplified, but I need to check for the `016b' first before I replace anything.

Comment: Why do you want to destroy information?

Comment: Kelly Bundy - I am not trying to destroy information. There are some complicated conversion issues involving GIS, fonts, and other things and a decision was made to simply remove the macron in certain instances (which is why I need to check for it first). I am not trying to create an ethical or philosophical discussion on accent marks, just need some helpful feedback on my question.

Comment: Reinderien - as far as I could see, that post only covered removing diacritics, not checking for them. I need to check that its there first.

Comment: "In this instance, 016b denotes that a macron accent mark is used over the u" - that's not what it means. `\u016b` means the Unicode code point with hex value 016b. That character happens to be ū, but the fact that it's an accented "u" is a complete coincidence.

Comment: Well the information is there and you want to remove it. But ok, if GIS etc truly can't handle it, then that's decent reason. Isn't clear from your question, hence I asked. Plenty of people are confused about string representations and ask for things they don't actually need.

Comment: user2357112 - point taken and forgive my unfamiliarity with these diacritics. How would you propose checking for a macron in unicode then? Assume the macron could hypothetically be with a u, or any other letter.

Comment: "I need to check for the `016b' first" Why? If it's not there, replace or normalize won't do any harm. Maybe show a more complete example for context?

Comment: tobias_k - I tried to craft my question in a generic sense, but the main reason is because I don't want to remove ALL diacritic values from the unicode, just the macron, which is why I needed to check for 016b first.

Comment: Noted. I updated my original question to clarify. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
place_name = u'K\u016bla Mountain'


if 0x016b in [ord(c) for c in place_name]:
    place_name = u'Kula Mountain'
print(place_name)
```

output:-

```
Kula Mountain
```

In your case, `0x016b` represents the Unicode code point for the character `'u'` and `ord()` take single character as an argument.so, you can use list comprehension in this

Comment: `0x016b in [ord(c) for c in place_name]` is an overly complicated way of saying `u'\u016b' in place_name`

Comment: Hey Steven - Your solution does work; however I just need to check for a macron period and u'\u016b'u' is specific to the 'u'.  I tried just using u'016b', but that didn't quite work.

Comment: Are you going to hardcode every possible string like that? And why would you change every place that happens to have a 'ū' to Kula Mountain?

Comment: Sorry, but no, it does not work nicely, or does not do what you want or think it does, because `0x016b` is _not_ any macron, but specifically "u with macron".

Answer (score 3):

You've misinterpreted your input.

The 016b does not denote a macron over the "u". Instead, `\u016b` is an escape sequence, representing the Unicode code point with hex value 016b. That code point happens to be ū, U+016B LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH MACRON, but the fact that it's an accented "u" has nothing to do with the "u" in the escape sequence.

Your string does not have a 0, 1, 6, or b in it. The string literal you wrote has those characters in it, but the string it evaluates to has a `ū` character in it. Searching for "016b" will not find a match.

If you want to remove macrons from your input, you can apply canonical decomposition to transform the composed character into separate "u" and combining macron (U+0304 COMBINING MACRON) code points, then remove the combining macrons:

```
import unicodedata

# NFD normalization applies canonical decomposition, splitting apart composed characters
decomposed_place_name = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', place_name)

# \N escape sequences let you refer to a code point by name.
# Alternatively, you could use '\u0304' to refer to it by hex numeric value.
place_name_without_macrons = decomposed_place_name.replace('\N{COMBINING MACRON}', '')
```

Comment: Nice, this seems to do exactly what OP wants, and I learned something new, too.

Comment: To make the code a bit more generic so it can handle other diacritics, `import regex as re` then normalise as above, then `place_name_without_diacritics = re.sub(r'\p{Mn}', '', decomposed_place_name)`

Comment: @Andj: Apparently they don't want to remove other diacritics, just macrons. That's useful for other people's use cases, though.

Comment: @user2357112, Thanks, that was the purpose of adding a generic solution. But didn't feel it was worth its own answer since your solution was sufficient for the question, I was aware the question specifically referred to macrons, although, the presence of a macron is intriguing, not what I would have expected.